# "Connection Refused erno 111" while connecting to GrapheneDB using PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, pythonanywhere, graphenedb

I'm trying to establish a connection to GrapheneDB.

I'm running this code on Spyder and its working perfectly fine.

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
from flask import Flask
#from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def hello_world():
    driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://hobby-dobhfgnijmdigbkelfmgifdl.dbs.graphenedb.com:24787", auth=basic_auth("username", "password"))
    session = driver.session()


#   session.run("CREATE (n:Object {name:'Mat'})")
    result = session.run("MATCH (n:Object) RETURN n.name AS name")
```

As soon as I run this code on Server (Pythonanywhere)

> Error appears: connect raise ServiceUnavailable("Failed to establish
>   connection to {!r} (reason {})".format(resolved_address, error))
>   neobolt.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to establish connection
>   to ('54.234.36.208', 24787) (reason [Errno 111] Connection refused)

I'm not sure what is wrong. GrapheneDB is also on the whitelist of python anywhere.

Comment: You won't be able to do it if you have free account on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: Would it be possible with a hacker account? Also, isn't graphenedb on the whitelist then why the restriction.

Comment: It should be possible on a hacker account. It looks like non-http/https connection, so it's not available on a free account.